# ffmpeg libx264rgb error

Tags: ffmpeg, video, libx264

When i was using ffmpeg i use libx264rgb to convert videos.

But when I converted a video there was a error.

I will put you a video so that you can see what happened.

Original:

https://archive.org/download/error_202109/Test.mp4

https://archive.org/download/error_202109/libx264.log

Converted in libx264rgb:

https://archive.org/download/error_202109/Test%20%281%29.mp4

https://archive.org/download/error_202109/libx264rgb.log

if you could fix the libx264rgb error?

Answer (score 0):

Recently, a bug was fixed in ffmpeg related to relaying of input color parameters onto the output. But this unmasked a bug in another component viz. updating color parameters when the scalers changes them. Till that is fixed, add `-colorspace rgb` as an output option with `libx264rgb`.